# Why I allocate 600 examples to a client but there are 700 when I train the model in TFF?

Tags: tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-federated

I met a strange problem when I used my created data set in TFF. I created a data set for federated training, where I allocate 5 clients examples as follows: 600 600 300 700 300. But when I trained them in model, I found the number of examples is 600 600 600 600 700. I was so confused. And then, I printed the process information of my created data set and checked the HDF5 file of the dataset, and both of them were 600 600 300 700 300. 
I use this code to see how many examples in the client in the HDF5 file, the result is 700:

```
len(f3["examples"][client_ids[3]]["label"].value)
```

I use this code to instance the data set and see how many examples in the client:

```
BAL3 = tff.simulation.hdf5_client_data.HDF5ClientData("BAL3.hdf5")

    num_clients_BAL3 = len(BAL3.client_ids)

    example_dataset = BAL3.create_tf_dataset_for_client(
        BAL3.client_ids[3]
    )
    example_element = next(iter(example_dataset))
    n = 0
    iter_ = iter(example_dataset)
    while(iter_):
      next(iter_)
      n = n+1
      print(n) #n stop at 600
```

I use this code to instance the data set of third client and debug:

```
BAL3 = tff.simulation.hdf5_client_data.HDF5ClientData("BAL3.hdf5")

example_dataset = BAL3.create_tf_dataset_for_client(
    BAL3.client_ids[3]
)
example_element = next(iter(example_dataset))
n = 0
iter_ = iter(example_dataset)
while(n < 601): #n<600 can work well
  example_element = next(iter_)
  n = n+1
  #print(n)

print(example_element['label'].numpy() )
plt.imshow(example_element['pixels'].numpy(), cmap='gray', aspect='equal')
plt.grid(False)
_=plt.show()
```

I allocated the third client 700 examples when I created the data set. But when I iterated data of this client I found it showed 600 examples. The tff HDF5 file showed 700 too.

Comment: I suspect you may have already done this, but worth a shot--can you iterate directly over client ids, IE, `for client in BAL3.client_ids...`, create the dataset for that client, and print the length? TFF [sorts](https://codesearch.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/tensorflow_federated/python/simulation/hdf5_client_data.py?q=f:tensorflow_federated+hdf5&g=0&l=51) the client ids it returns, so this could in theory change the order from that which you expect.

Comment: Yes, I see that TFF sorts the client ids return. The order is not same as my created order any more. You are so nice and brilliant. I am so sorry about my poor English. I am a student and new in TFF. Thank you for your patient guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the loop here: since TFF [sorts](https://source.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/tensorflow_federated/python/simulation/hdf5_client_data.py;l=51?q=f:tensorflow_federated%20hdf5&g=0) the Client IDs it returns, one generally cannot rely on the ordering in the Client IDs being the same as the order of construction.